# Can a matching be empty and an augmenting path of length 1?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm studying matchings in graph theory. The definition of matching that I have in my textbook states: "A set M of independent edges in a graph G = (V, E) is called a matching.".

Later, the definition of an augmenting path (referring to bipartite graphs with
bipartition { A, B }) is given: "A path in G which starts in A at an unmatched vertex and then contains, alternately, edges from E $\setminus$ M and from M, is an alternating path with respect to M. An alternating path P that ends in an unmatched vertex of B is called an augmenting path, because we can use it to turn M into a larger matching.".

Now my question is: is it possible for an empty matching to exist? In the sense that M = Ø is considered a matching in all respects? And, if so, can a possible augmenting path of M be a single edge between two unmatched nodes?

Comment: Yes of course. Generally, for a graph matching, you start from an empty matching and you match vertices greedily (by finding length 1 augmenting paths) until you can't, then you start searching for some longer augmenting paths...

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the response. Now I finally understand!